# Compare two dataframes and create new values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes, one that looks like this:

```
>df1
             SNP                Symbols
    1 rs11807834          GRIN1,SETD1A
    2  rs3729986      MADD,STAC3,SPI1
    3 rs61937595 NDUFA4L2,STAC3,CAMK2N1
```

and another that looks like this

```
>df2

   Symbol    Score
1   GRIN1      167
2  SETD1A      160
3    MADD      164
4   STAC3       12
5 CAMK2N1        3
6 NDUFA4L2       0
7   SPI1         0
```

I want to get the Symbol with the highest score for each `SNP` column, and then find the "proportion" that score has. So it would look like this:

```
>result
    
          SNP                 Symbols        Highest.Score   Score.Proportion  
   rs11807834            GRIN1,SETD1A                GRIN1               0.51                        
    rs2600490          MADD,STAC3,SPI1                MADD               0.91                         
    rs3729986   NDUFA4L2,STAC3,CAMK2N1               STAC3               0.8
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

```
df1 <- data.frame("SNP" = c("rs11807834", "rs3729986", "rs61937595" ), "Symbols" = c("GRIN1,SETD1A", "MADD,STAC3,SPI1", "NDUFA4L2,STAC3,CAMK2N1"))

df2 <- data.frame("Symbol" = c("GRIN1", "SETD1A", "MADD", "STAC3", "CAMK2N1", "NDUFA4L2", "SPI1"), "Score" = c(167, 160, 164,12,3,0,0))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dataframes and retrieve values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465726/compare-two-dataframes-and-retrieve-values) I don't see any differences to what you posted yesterday.

Comment: @jamie its similar, except I want an additional column (containing the Score.Proportion).

Answer (score 1):

Separate genes to rows, group by snp, get proportion, then get rows with maximum scores:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(Symbols, sep = ",") %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Symbols" = "Symbol")) %>% 
  group_by(SNP) %>% 
  mutate(Score.Proportion = Score/sum(Score)) %>% 
  slice_max(Score) %>% 
  rename(Highest.Score = Score) %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   SNP        Symbols Highest.Score Score.Proportion
#   <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1 rs11807834 GRIN1             167            0.511
# 2 rs3729986  MADD              164            0.932
# 3 rs61937595 STAC3              12            0.8
```